# Selector CSS para elemento sin clase?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

dentro de elementos DIV hay 3 SPAN, 2 con alguna CLASE CSS y otro SIN CLASE.
Como hacer para seleccionar con selectores CSS el span que NO tiene NINGUNA CLASE, yo probé con span:not(.AAA) pero no logro poner ambas clases porque no funciona. Como los SPAN sin clase pueden estar en cualquier posicion dentro de los DIVs tengo que seleccionarlos de algún modo.

```
<div>
<span class="AAA">AAA</span>
<span class="BBB">BBB</span>
<span>CCC</span>
</div>

<div>
<span class="AAA">AAA</span>
<span>CCC</span>
<span class="BBB">BBB</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como has dicho, puedes hacerlo con el `:not()` pero, en vez de añadirle las clases concatenadas dentro debes añadir más de uno.

```
span:not(.AAA, .BBB)
```

no funcionará pues el selector espera solo un elemento, no un conjunto de elementos, la forma de hacerlo sería:

```
span:not(.AAA):not(.BBB)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Rabegi!, no encontraba buena informacion sobre como usar :not.

Answer (score 3):

La solución de @Rabegi es correcta pero pongo otra más general. Usando `:not()` y un selector de atributo se pueden seleccionar los `span` que no tengan clase, da igual que clase tengan los otros:

```css
span:not([class]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="AAA">AAA</span>
  <span class="BBB">BBB</span>
  <span>CCC</span>
  <span class="DDD">DDD</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="AAA">AAA</span>
  <span>CCC</span>
  <span class="BBB">BBB</span>
  <span class="DDD">DDD</span>
</div>
```